# Force client to preload audio files from specific folder

Tags: javascript

I developed a soundboard where you have many buttons, if you click on a button then a sound plays. Is there a way to force a client to preload all audio files from a specific folder, so they are available after the page loaded even if the internet connection breaks?

The only way I know is to create a variable for each audio file, add an `id` to each button and add event listeners for the click event.

Example:

```
<button class="button" id="soundfile01">
    Test
</button>

...

var soundfile01 = new Audio("audio/soundfile01.mp3");    

$("#soundfile01").click(function() {
    soundfile01.play();
});
```

But this is alot of work for each button.

I could also give each button an `id` with the name of the audio file and then code it like this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var audio = new Audio("audio/"+id+".mp3");

    audio.play();
});
```

Then it does not work anymore if the internet connection is lost, but it is important for me that it also works if the page was already loaded and the internet gets disconnected, because I plan to use the soundboard on my smartphone, preload the page at home and leave the website open the whole day so I can use it everywhere even If I don't have internet connection.

I know I could make an app, but then only owners of the platforms for which the app was developed for could use it, it would be alot of work to maintain or update several apps.

Is the code from the first example the only way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mixture of both approaches will help you out.  Firstly, create an audio object for each button, and then use the button click event to play each of those objects...

```
// create an object that has an audio object for each button
var audio = {};
$(".button").each(function() {
    audio[this.id] = new Audio("audio/" + this.id + ".mp3");
});

// assign the click event handler
$(".button").click(function() {
    audio[this.id].play();
});
```

**Note:** I removed `$(this).attr("id")` as you can just use `this.id` inside jQuery handlers.

I'd also recommend looking at using a data attribute for each button attached to an mp3 file, something like...

```
<button id="sound01" class=".button" data-mp3-file="audio/some-filename.mp3">Sound 1</button>
```

Then the code to create the audio objects would become...

```
audio[this.id] = new Audio($(this).data("mp3-file"));
```

This resolves the issue of always having to have button ids match a filename, which may become a problem at some point.

You could take this further and handle the load event of each audio object, setting each button initially disabled and only enabling them when the audio object has successfully loaded.  This type of approach just makes it easier to add things like this as you only have 1 piece of code for setup, and 1 piece of code for the buttons.